# Can a user exit a contenteditable with a key?

Tags: javascript, html, events, contenteditable, keydown

I currently have a content editable that allows users to change text within a span. I want to make it so that the content editable container closes after the user presses the Enter key.

```
  container.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('targetSpan')){
                document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyDownEvents);
                document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) =>{
                    if (event.key === 'Enter'){
                        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvents);
                       //function to also close contenteditable container
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I currently have an event listener that is removed upon click on the span that has the contenteditable attribute. I want to add back the event listener when the user clicks the enter key. However, I also want the contenteditable container to close

Comment: It's almost always wrong to add an event listener inside another event listener. Every time you click on the container you're adding another `keydown` listener.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're doing here. Besides that, instead of removing/re-adding the event listener, consider simply adding an if statement to determine whether to execute the code. This simplifies stuff a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('targetSpan')){
    container.setAttribute('contenteditable',true);
    container.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey);
  }
});

container.addEventListener('blur',(event) => {
    container.removeEventListener('keydown',checkKey)
});

function checkKey(e) {
  if(e.key === 'Enter') {
    container.blur();
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="targetSpan" contenteditable="true" id="container">I'm a dummy text, edit me</span>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you don't need the `click` event, and `.targetSpan` class checking, you can shorten your code, by doing something like this.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey);

function checkKey(e) {
  if(e.key === 'Enter') {
    container.blur();
  }
}
```

In this case, there's no need to check for the `click` event and attach the `keydown` inside of it. `contenteditable=true` let's you type inside your element [by design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable#browser_compatibility). The `keydown` event listener was left the way it was, in case you need to remove it at some point.